# AWS EKS Node Group IP Limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I'd like to launch many small pods that use very little resources in an EKS Kubernetes cluster. I have come across this issue that, given the `T3.Small` instance type, only 12 IPs can be allocated. Accordingly, I can create only 7 pods and the rest of them will stuck on `Pending` status with errors such as `Too many pods` and `failed to assign an IP address to container`.

Since my pods do not really use much resources, it would very silly if I change the instance type to something larger and more expensive as I really do not need a lot of CPU or RAM.

How can I fix this problem? Is there any configuration that I can manually do using the `kubectl` command to allow for more pods running on the same node?

UPDATE:

Apparently, EKS does not autoscale when reaching the IP limit.

Comment: when you say, 7 pods are coming up and the remaining 5 remain in a pending state.  in that context, can you dump `kubectl get pod -A -owide |grep -i <NODE-NAME>` and add its output to the question. ?

Comment: @P....: The error is `1 too many pods`